# How to use list comprenhension in Ocaml

Tags: list, haskell, ocaml, list-comprehension

This code is in Haskell. How can i do the same thing in OCAML?

```
perfect n = [x | x<-[1..n], sum(f x) == x]
f x = [i | i<-[1..x-1], x `mod` i ==0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Jeffrey's answer is correct, using appropriate libraries (in this case, sequence), you can get something that is similar in terseness and semantics to the Haskell style:

```
module S = Sequence
let sum = S.fold (+) 0
let f x = S.filter (fun i -> x mod i = 0) S.(1 -- (x-1))
let perfect n = S.filter (fun x -> sum (f x) = x) S.(1 -- n)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using many (really nice) features of Haskell that don't exist in OCaml.

For list comprehensions, you can use `List.filter`.

For the notation `[x .. y]` you can use this range function:

```
let range a b =
    let rec go accum i =
        if i > b then List.rev accum else go (i :: accum) (i + 1)
    in
    go [] a
```

For `sum` you can use this:

```
let sum = List.fold_left (+) 0
```

Comment: Minor detail: going negatively from b to a would avoid the additional traversal of the list by List.rev :)

Comment: Yes, I thought of this later. Thanks!